# Expectation of a type of bivariate lognormal

Tags: probability, expected-value, lognormal-distribution

Suppose $S_1 \sim e^\mathbf{X}$ where $\mathbf{X} \sim N(\mu, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, $\mathbf{X}$ is a bivariate normal distribution then what is the following,

$$ E\left[ \theta_1^\intercal S_1 \right] $$
where $\theta_1$ is a 2 x 1 constant vector?

Thanks.

EDIT: Is it just $\theta_1^\intercal E[S_1]$? And $E[S_1]_i = e^{\mu_i + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma_{ii}}$.

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the tag "self-study".

Comment: No, it isn't a homework question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion $E[\theta_1^TS_1]=\theta_1^TE[S_1]$ is correct. Also, since $e^X$ is [multivariate log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#/Multivariate_log-normal), you can use the expected value formula given in the page, which is same as yours: $E[S_1]_i = e^{\mu_i + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma_{ii}}$.

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: I don't know actually.

Comment: finmath, I don't know either, but you yourself can upvote this answer.